# Error Using a plugin after installing it with Bower

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-plugins, bower

I'm a newbie (intern), and I'm working on a bootstrap/jquery environment.

I'm trying to add a [password strength](https://github.com/ablanco/jquery.pwstrength.bootstrap) feature to my website's login app. In my login app folder (contact_sid) I've installed the pwdstrength plugin using bower. The files are stored in bower_components.

Now, I'm trying to use the pwstrength() function in my main.js file. As shown on github, I invoke the plugin using  $(':password').pwstrength();
When I run the app, I get an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).pwstrength is not a function
```

Any help would be really appreciated. I think if I copy the pwdstrength.js function inside my main.js, it works (kinda), but it's obviously bad practice.

Comment: Also, if anyone is curious, here is the web app: https://auth.humanitarian.id

Comment: I'd recommend you to start using grant for packaging your 3rd party & your scripts....otherwise, please write how the scripts from bower are deployed to your app....

Comment: I just used [bower install https://github.com/ablanco/jquery.pwstrength.bootstrap.git]

Comment: Does grunt do the same?

Comment: grunt is used for building and deploying js, css & html. when using grunt with bower, grunt is checking the dependencies written in your bower json file and add them automatically to your index.html file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you're receiving means that your plugin hasn't been loaded, so you're trying to call a function that doesn't exist.

Ensure that you have loaded/load "pwstrength" *before* calling it with jQuery, like this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/bower_components/pwstrength.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/js/main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Check out [the examples on GitHub](http://www.github.com/ablanco/jquery.pwstrength.bootstrap/tree/master/examples) to see how the author intended its usage.

Also, welcome to Stack Overflow. Nothing wrong with being an intern; everyone starts somewhere! :)

Comment: Where do I load this? In the front end (html)? Thank you so much for the nice words, really appreciate the support!

Comment: Indeed; either that, or you could prepend your `main.js` file with the contents of [pwstrength.js](http://www.github.com/ablanco/jquery.pwstrength.bootstrap/blob/master/dist/pwstrength-bootstrap-1.2.7.js). Just make sure that "pwstrength" gets loaded before you call it.

Comment: I added the scripts to the html file, but there are still problems in the backend. It says the same: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).pwstrength is not a function... I guess I'll try adding the pwdstrength.js to main.js, but that isn't good programming...right?

Comment: I solved the problem. Needed to add the script to the right html file.